# Issues with attaching scatterplot with class labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a scatterplot that visualize 10 different classes with different label colors. In addition, I'd like a legend that tells which color corresponds to which class. However, the legend part does not work and my output looks like this:

[image]

My code looks as following, where val: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.scatter(x=new_data[0], y=new_data[1], alpha=0.5, marker='o', c=yTrainNp, label=val)
plt.title('2D representation of PCA analysis')
plt.xlabel('1st principal')
plt.ylabel('2nd principal')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Any ideas about how display a list of different colored circles with their corresponding class label?

Comment: You could try seaborn's [scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) which automatically creates an appropriate legend when you supply the `hue=` parameter.  Something like `sns.scatterplot(x=new_data[0], y=new_data[1], alpha=0.5, hue=yTrainNp)` should work in your case.

Comment: You are right - it did work with the hue= parameter!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to divide your one plot commands into several different ones.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
vals =  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_data = np.random.normal(size=(200, 2)) # Making up some data
# Making up some colors. I assume you have as many colors as you have labels.
# I'm using MPL cycle color, "C0", "C1", because I didn't want to mess with RGB values.
colors = np.array(['C' + str(i) for i in np.random.randint(0, high=9+1, size=(200,))])
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i, color in enumerate(sorted(set(colors))): # Unique colors
    plt.scatter(x=new_data[colors == color, 0],  # Slices arrays
                y=new_data[colors == color, 1], 
                alpha=0.5, 
                marker='o', 
                c=color, 
                label=vals[i])
plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I've seen this kinda sophisticated solution, but didn't understand the mechanics until now. Thank you, this made sense!